# Object of type Company is not JSON serializable when writing tests

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm having an issue in Django RestFramework in testing.
I have the following test:

```
def test_update_coupon(self):
        response = self.make_coupon_request(
            kind="put",
            version="v1",
            id=2,
            data=self.valid_coupon_data
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Where make_coupon_request has a return of:

```
return self.client.put(
    reverse("coupon",
        kwargs={
            "version": kwargs["version"],
            "pk": kwargs["id"]
        }
    ),
    data=json.dumps(kwargs["data"]),
    content_type='application/json'
)
```

and valid_coupon_data where the problem is occurring is:

```
self.valid_coupon_data = {
    "company": Company.objects.get(id=1),
    "name": "Coupon Updated",
    "added": "2018-11-30",
    "code": "TESTCODE"
}
```

**edit - An example Company that would be in this structure is:**

```
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "test",
                "added": "2018-11-30"
            },
```

So the total structure would look like:

```
self.valid_coupon_data = {
        "company": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "test",
                    "added": "2018-11-30"
                },
        "name": "Coupon Updated",
        "added": "2018-11-30",
        "code": "TESTCODE"
    }
```

The error I am getting is in *make_coupon_request* that json.dumps cannot serialize *valid_coupon_data*:

```
"TypeError: Object of type Company is not JSON serializable"
```

I have a serializer for Company:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    coupons = CouponSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ("name", "added", "coupons")
```

And for coupon:

```
class CouponSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Coupon
        fields = ("company", "name", "added", "code")
```

Basically I know that somehow I need to use a serializer in order to make my test work, as json.dumps isn't accepting the raw Company object... but I am not sure how nor do I quite understand why.

Here are my 2 models for reference:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Companies"


class Coupon(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='coupons')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

Comment: I don't understand the sequence of code here. Why are you dumping things to JSON explicitly in your test, rather than letting the serializer do it?

Comment: The make_coupon_request function calls to a url with the name 'coupon' so that I can test a PUT request on the api I created using the rest frameeork. That is why the reverse("coupon", kwargs={#etc}  in self.client.put. Am I doing something wrong or stupid? Is there a better way to utilize my serializer to test such a PUT through the api created?

Comment: Can you show an example of what the data for the PUT should look like?

Comment: That's the valid_coupon_data bit where Company is a sub object with the fields in the company serializer

Comment: Yes but you need to show the complete structure.

Comment: Okay edited - I think I added what you were asking for - sorry if it's unclear still

Comment: I guess the point is - I am clearly doing this in the wrong way. There must be a logical way to combine a linked model with an object to then test an API endpoint for the PUT method. I picked the 'data=json.dumps(kwargs["data"]),' way of doing it because some tutorial online said to do it that way. But is there a smarter way of doing this? Can I just send the serialized structure directly? I'm going to try that. It's tough picking up a new framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a python object via a json in your test, this section

```
self.valid_coupon_data = {
"company": Company.objects.get(id=1),   # This is the error point! you are passing python object not a json.
"name": "Coupon Updated",
"added": "2018-11-30",
"code": "TESTCODE"
}
```

And passing just integer value like other answers will not work either. you should pass json of company object too. like this:

```
company = Company.objects.get(id=1)

self.valid_coupon_data = {
"company": {
     "id": company.id,
     "name": company.name,
     "added": company.added
},
"name": "Coupon Updated",
"added": "2018-11-30",
"code": "TESTCODE"
}
```

**Note** 
By the way if you are using django rest, then the way you are returning data in your views is not correct. use `to_representation` or `serializer.data` methods. it's not that well to use json.dump when you have a powerfull library like `django-rest-framework`. You can also return json as is with `Response` library of django-rest. like `return Response(jsonData)`

If you want more clear answer, please provide `make_coupon_request` method codes. to see what's going on in there.

Answer (score 2):

The problem *may*  lies in this statement,

```
self.valid_coupon_data = {
    "company": Company.objects.get(id=1), # here
    "name": "Coupon Updated",
    "added": "2018-11-30",
    "code": "TESTCODE"
}
```

It's clear that you are trying to send a json data and unfortunately it contains a *non-serializable data* of `Company` type.

---

According to the **`CouponSerializer`** you'd provided, the below json is enough to create/update  the **`Coupon`** instance.

```
{
    "company": 1, # provide only integer value
    "name": "Coupon Updated",
    "added": "2018-11-30",
    "code": "TESTCODE"
}
```

Comment: Hello - that is where I thought the issue might be due to passing Company type as it is non-serializable data. The problem is when I change it to:
`"company": 1,` I receive the error `ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Coupon.company" must be a "Company" instance.`

Comment: But my add coupons test uses the exact same data and there are no issues creating, just when I update

Comment: can you add the traceback of both cases? Case1. your old code and Case2. after trying this